# Anko DSL recyclerview strange behaviour while adding items

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

So I initially have 6  items in my RecyclerView. When I add an item I got a toast that's says that new item is added and shows that adapter items increased. But the new item is a duplicate of the item "6". Then I add to more items and ther are all "6". Then I scroll up and down and I see items "byButton"(that's the name of button added by clicking a button) that are between those duplicates of "6". And after a while the whole RecycleView reset and I still have 6 items just like at the beginning. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
class ConnectDeviceUI(val listAdapter: DeviceListAdapter): AnkoComponent<ConnectBleActivity> {
    lateinit var addItemButton: FloatingActionButton
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<ConnectBleActivity>): View = with(ui) {
        return relativeLayout() {
            lparams(width= matchParent, height = matchParent)

            textView("List of BLE devices"){
                setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Large)
            }

            addItemButton = floatingActionButton {
                imageResource = android.R.drawable.ic_input_add
            }.lparams{
                margin = dip(10)
                alignParentBottom()
                alignParentEnd()
                alignParentRight()
                gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.END
            }

            recyclerView(){
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true)
                lparams(width= matchParent, height = matchParent)
                adapter = listAdapter

            }
        }
    }
}


class RowLayout(): AnkoComponent<ViewGroup>{
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<ViewGroup>): View = with(ui) {
        return linearLayout(){
            lparams(width= matchParent, height = wrapContent)
            setPadding(0,dip(50),0,dip(50))

            textView {
                id = R.id.ble_item
                setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Large)
                setPadding(0,0,dip(100),0)
            }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = wrapContent )

            button{
                id = R.id.ble_item_button
            }.lparams(width = wrapContent, height = wrapContent)

        }
    }
}


class ConnectBleActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AnkoLogger {

    lateinit var BleDevicesList: ArrayList<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        BleDevicesList = arrayListOf("1", "2","3", "4", "5", "6")
        var adapter = DeviceListAdapter(BleDevicesList)
        var ui = ConnectDeviceUI(adapter)
        ui.setContentView(this)
        ui.addItemButton.onClick {
            adapter.put()
            toast("New item added. Number of items: ${adapter.itemCount} ")
        }

    }
}




class DeviceListAdapter(var deviceList: ArrayList<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<DeviceListHolder>(){
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DeviceListHolder?, position: Int) {
        holder?.bindItems(deviceList[position])
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): DeviceListHolder {
        return DeviceListHolder(RowLayout().createView(AnkoContext.create(parent!!.context, parent)))
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return deviceList.size
    }

    fun put(){
        val randomString = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        deviceList.add(deviceList.lastIndex, "byButton")
        notifyItemInserted(deviceList.lastIndex)
    }

    fun drop(){
        deviceList.removeAt(deviceList.lastIndex)
        notifyItemRemoved(deviceList.lastIndex)
    }


}

class DeviceListHolder(var view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val name: TextView = view.find(R.id.ble_item)
    val bt_name: Button = view.find(R.id.ble_item_button)
    fun bindItems(listItem: String){
        name.text = listItem
        bt_name.text = "Test"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `List.lastIndex()` after modifying the list itself, results in different values being updated in the model and the view

```
deviceList.add(deviceList.lastIndex, "byButton")
notifyItemInserted(deviceList.lastIndex)
```

The notification tells the `RecyclerView` to update the last item only. This contains a `"6"` while the old position is not updated at all. To resolve this issue, you have to use the same index for both.

```
val index = deviceList.lastIndex
deviceList.add(index, "byButton")
notifyItemInserted(index)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the reason when I add item on index "0" its working fine :D